# Unable to get Album Art from Spotify in Objective C using kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtworkData

Tags: objective-c, macos, spotify, albumart, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm tweaking a forked TouchBar application which shows widgets on the Mac TouchBar, and am trying to get album art to display on the NowPlaying Widget. This is the [project](https://github.com/knives-repo/EnergyBar/tree/knives-patches).

Currently, I'm having issues with this piece of code:

```
- (void)updateInfo
{
    MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^(NSDictionary *info)
        {
            NSString *album = [info objectForKey:kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoAlbum];
            NSString *artist = [info objectForKey:kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtist];
            NSString *title = [info objectForKey:kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoTitle];
            NSData *artworkData = [info objectForKey:kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtworkData];
        
        NSImage *albumart = nil;
        if (nil != artworkData && ![artworkData isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        {
            albumart = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:artworkData];
        }
        
        if (nil != albumart)
        {
            self.appIcon = albumart;
        }
        
        if (self.album != album || self.artist != artist || self.title != title || self.albumArt != albumart)
        {
            self.album = album;
            self.artist = artist;
            self.title = title;
            self.albumArt = albumart;

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                postNotificationName:NowPlayingInfoNotification
                object:self];
        }
    });
}
```

The main issue I'm running into is that the album art data only shows up for about half a second after the song starts, afterwards, it disappears. My theory is that kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtworkData is the wrong thing to use to get artwork data, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Spotify and Music don't update their album art data immediately if  pulling from the Notification Center. The solution is to add a delay of about 50ms.